# WPF DataTemplate - Event fired when a new item is added to Collection?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol

When a new item is added to the `Flights` collection a new `TabItem` is added to the `TabControl`. When a new tab is added, I need to call a method on the Chart control.  The problem is I can't figure out the right event to handle.

My XAML looks something like the following:

```
<TabControl Name="chartControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Flights}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WindowsFormHost Name="winHost">
                <legacy:Chart></legacy:Chart>
            </WindowsFormHost>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

- I tried handling the `Loaded` on the `TabControl`,
  but *duh* that's only fired once.
- I    attempted a `DataTemplate`
  `Trigger`    on the `RoutedEvent`
  `FrameWorkElement.Loaded` but I'm pretty sure that's not meant for my situation
- I tried an EventSetter but that
  didn't quite work the way I want
  either

I attempted a few other things, but I don't quite remember them all.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your XAML correctly, you are creating a single Chart control for the TabControl and changing its data when the TabItem changes? If so, you should be able to use the `SelectionChanged` event.

You might be better off putting your Chart control in the ItemTemplate so it automatically loads the selected `Flights` data when the user switches tabs or adds a new one.

Comment: I don't think SelectionChanged is what I need because when the tabitem is loaded, that's when I need to call a method on the chart control :o(

Comment: In that case, there is a TabItemLoaded event. Add a style for target type `{x:Type TabItem}` to the `TabControl.Resources` and use an EventSetter to set the Loaded event. An alternative is to move your chart control from the `TabControl.ContentTemplate` and put it in the `TabControl.ItemTemplate` instead and run the Loaded event on that.

Comment: I think originally I avoided the EventSetter because it fired the Loaded event on every existing tab, not just a newly added one. I guess I'll tinker with this and see if I can just handle only the new tabs. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Flights` collection should be of type [ObservableCollection<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx). The ItemsSource binding in xaml will subscribe to its *CollectionChanged* event and add/remove tabs. As for calling the method on the Chart, does the WindowsFormHost have a Loaded event? Because a new one will be created for each tab that's created.

Comment: I'd recommend changing it to an ObservableCollection because List<> will not update the UI automatically when a new item is added, ObservableCollection<> will

Comment: Flights is of type List<>. The TabControl's DataContext is set to my ViewModel, which has a property called Flights which is List<Flight> so I don't have the CollectionChanged event. I don't think. :o(

Comment: well right now the UI is updating when the Flights collection is updated.

Comment: Change your viewmodel's Flights to be of IList<Flight>, you can then pass the List<> of Flights into the constructor of ObservableCollection<> and use it the same because ObservableCollection<> implements IList<>

Comment: And I just checked, WindowsFormHost *does* have a *Loaded* event. Subscribe to that, and call the method on the Chart.

Comment: the issue I ran into with handling that event is it only fired that event once :o( when I added future tabs, it doesn't trigger the Loaded event. :o( There is also a Load event on the Chart, but even that is only called once. :s

Comment: Your post says you handled Loaded on the TabControl. Do it on the WindowsFormHost.

Comment: I tried on the WindowsFormHost as well, it was one of the things I tried but forgot I tried :( (it's only fired when the entire tabcontrol is initially loaded)

Comment: You are adding the WindowsFormsHost in the ContentTemplate of the tab control, so it is basically a part of the TabControl itself. Move it to the ItemTemplate to make it part of a TabItem and it should run the Loaded event anytime a new TabItem is created.

Comment: that explains why my event is fired only once. when I move the stuff to an ItemTemplate, it really screws up the layout. bleh! Well, thanks for the halp you two! :)